# I am using apache-camel framework now I want to send multiple exchages

Tags: java, apache-camel

Here i have classes A,B

```
List<A> A1=new ArrayList<>(); //some data
List<B> B1=new ArrayList<>(); //some data
List<A> A2=new ArrayList<>(); //some data
List<B> B2=new ArrayList<>(); //some data
```

Now i am grouping it in another list object

```
List<List> list=new ArrayList<>();
list.add(A1);
list.add(B1);
list.add(A2);
list.add(B2);
```

Now i am setting in exchange object and returning

```
exchange.getIn().setBody(list);
```

My question is, the 'list' object or exchange which i want to split and send it to a different channels based on each data(class type).
i want to send this data to different files(4 files).

Comment: Sure. What is the question?

Comment: My question is, the 'list' object or exchange which i want to split and send it to a different channels based on each data(class type).<br />
i want to send this data to different files(4 files).

Comment: That's not a question. That's a list of requirements. If you mean "how do I do that" - well, where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for a [Splitter](http://camel.apache.org/splitter.html). The idea of this EIP is to decompose a message into a set of smaller messages that can be processed individually.

Given that the content may differ from one of these smaller messages to the next, it sounds like the recipient of your splitter may be a content-based route.